# Difference between iterator and generator in for of loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, for-of-loop

Lets have an iterator and a generator created to working similarly.

What is the reason they behave differently in `for of` loop if it contains break or return statement?

The generator is finished while the iterator still goes after the end of the loop.

```js
function *createGenerator() { 
  for ( let i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    yield i;
  }
}

function createIterator() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return arr[ Symbol.iterator ]();
}

function runForOfLoopOn( iterable ) {
  for ( const item of iterable ) {
    if ( item == 2 ) { 
      break;
    }
  }
}

const iterator = createIterator();
const generator = createGenerator();

runForOfLoopOn( iterator );
runForOfLoopOn( generator );

console.log( 'Iterator is done:', iterator.next().done );
console.log( 'Generator is done:', generator.next().done );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when a `for of` loop contains a `break` or `return` statement?

When the body of the loop completes abruptly (with a `throw` or `return` statement) or is broken out of, the [`IteratorClose` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-iteratorclose) will be called. This which basically amounts to invoking the iterator's `.return()` method with no arguments if the iterator object has such a method.

> What is the reason an iterator and a generator behave differently?

That only the generator has such a [`return()` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-generator.prototype.return). The [`ArrayIterator`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array-iterator-objects) you created does not have such a method as there is nothing it would need to do. The primary purpose of the `return()` method is to release resources, e.g. by triggering `finally` clauses in a generator function, but array iterators don't use any. It *could* clear its reference to the iterated array (which would be "closing" the iterator), but this was deemed unnecessary as array iterators are typically garbage-collected right away.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't expect such a good answer so quickly :) I came across the docs at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols and even didn't find anything about the `return` method in iterators. Now, thanks to you I'll know it :)